# Webpack alias '@' for a specific node_module

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have installed a module from npm and find out that it used a alias '@' to resolve it's components.  The issues is that I am using '@' as alias of my source directory too.

When I run 'build', there is an error :
**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components**

The npm module cannot be built.  How can I specific the '@' alias for that module?

Thanks
Wilson